# Knockout optionValues modeling issue

Tags: knockout.js, combobox

I'm working on a nested form with different types of controls (http://jsfiddle.net/gZC5k/993/ )  that has an issue that appeared when adding a dropdown control.

I have this in my HTML

```
                        <tr class='person'>
                        <td>Gender</td>
                        <td>
                            <select data-bind="options: optionGender, value: gender"></select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

and this in the model

```
    self.contacts = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(contacts, function (contact) {
    return {
        firstName: ko.observable(contact.firstName),
        lastName: ko.observable(contact.lastName),
        isKey: ko.observable(contact.isKey),
        gender: ko.observable(contact.gender),
        phones: ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(contact.phones, function (phone) {
            return {
                type: ko.observable(phone.type),
                number: ko.observable(phone.number),
                calls: ko.observableArray(phone.calls)
            };
        })),
        addresses: ko.observableArray(contact.addresses),
        optionGender: ["Male", "Female"]
    };
}));

self.addContact = function () {
    self.contacts.push({
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
        isKey: "false",
        gender: "Female",
        phones: ko.observableArray(),
        addresses: ko.observableArray()
    });
};
```

when I inititally load the data, I can edit all values and the corresponding JSON is o.k. When adding a new Person, things go wrong.

when all stuff related to the Gender field is removed, the form works ok (see http://jsfiddle.net/gZC5k/995/) . I assume that I its a matter of putting the

```
            optionGender: ["Male", "Female"],
```

in the wrong place, but can't figure out where it should be.

Answer (score 0):

thought I found it by repeating optionGender in the addContact function  ( at http://jsfiddle.net/gZC5k/997/)

```
var optionGender = [
"Male",
"Female"];

var ContactsModel = function (contacts) {
var self = this;
self.contacts = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(contacts, function (contact) {
    return {
        firstName: ko.observable(contact.firstName),
        lastName: ko.observable(contact.lastName),
        isKey: ko.observable(contact.isKey),
        gender: ko.observable(contact.gender),
        phones: ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(contact.phones, function (phone) {
            return {
                type: ko.observable(phone.type),
                number: ko.observable(phone.number),
                calls: ko.observableArray(phone.calls)
            };
        })),
        addresses: ko.observableArray(contact.addresses),
        optionGender: optionGender,
    };
}));

self.addContact = function () {
    self.contacts.push({
        firstName: ko.observable(""),
        lastName: ko.observable(""),
        isKey: ko.observable("true"),
        gender: ko.observable("Female"),
        optionGender: optionGender,
        phones: ko.observableArray(),
        addresses: ko.observableArray()
    });
};
```

But This results in having the option list in the resulting JSON, like this

```
[
{
"firstName": "",
"lastName": "",
"isKey": "true",
"gender": "Male",
"optionGender": [
  "Male",
  "Female"
],
"phones": [],
"addresses": []
},
{
"firstName": "",
"lastName": "",
"isKey": "true",
"gender": "Female",
"optionGender": [
  "Male",
  "Female"
],
"phones": [],
"addresses": []
}
]
```

So I'm still looking for the solution..